# ISO C99 and above do not support implicit function declaration

Tags: nuvoton

i am trying to make a uart code for nuvorton m0516LAN but i am facing this issue

RTE/Device/M0516LAN/retarget.c(337): error: call to undeclared function 'asm'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

here is the handler function

```
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
    asm("MOVS    r0, #4                        \n"
        "MOV     r1, LR                        \n"
        "TST     r0, r1                        \n" /*; check LR bit 2 */
        "BEQ     1f                            \n" /*; stack use MSP */
        "MRS     R0, PSP                       \n" /*; stack use PSP, read PSP */
        "MOV     R1, LR                        \n" /*; LR current value */
        "B       Hard_Fault_Handler            \n"
        "1:                                    \n"
        "MRS     R0, MSP                       \n" /*; LR current value */
        "B       Hard_Fault_Handler            \n"
        ::[Hard_Fault_Handler] "r" (Hard_Fault_Handler) // input
    );
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code. Place a line consisting of three backticks above and below your text to indicate it should be treated literally without wrapping or other treatment of special characters. Beyond that the error is pretty clear. You are using a function call that the compiler does not know about. You need to include the appropriate header or compiler flag to enable support for inline assembler. Since you didn't tell us which C compiler your are using and on which platform you are compiling the code we can only guess what you need to do.